# asp.net webforms durandaljs 2.0 request querystring

Tags: asp.net, knockout.js, routes, webforms, durandal

I'm currently working with asp.net 3.5 web forms but I'm having trouble getting the values from the querystring. How would I go about doing this?

I have a webforms page with links to itself [these initialise durandal]

```
            <li>Go to <a href="#/123">Details</a></li>
            <li>Go to <a href="#Location/123">Location</a></li>
```

Which displays the shell and all but the it doesn't pick up the param 123 from the string.

```
return {
    router: router,
    items: items,
    activate: function () {
        router.map([
            { route: ['#/:ref', 'Property/:ref'], moduleId: 'viewmodels/property', title: 'Property Details', nav: true },
            { route: 'Location/:ref', moduleId: 'viewmodels/location', title: 'Location Details', nav: true }
        ]).buildNavigationModel();

        return router.activate();
    }
```

I've also tried setting activate: function () as activate: function (ref) but that doesn't seem to intercept the params at all.

Any help would be most appreciated?
I know there shouldn't be a problem when mixing durandaljs with webforms but are there any which I should be aware of?

Thanks.

Comment: The router passes the querystring into the activate function as a serialized object. You can also get the querystring from `router.activeInstruction()`

Comment: Thanks Tyrsius. Do you have a code sample which I may look at? Or point me to one?

Comment: No, but you can get this same info from the [docs page](http://durandaljs.com/documentation/Using-The-Router/). The last parameter passed to the `activate` function (after all the route parameters) is a hash of the querystring.

Comment: Thanks Tyrsius. Explains why I had trouble sorting it out as all the examples are based on v1.2. Durandal v2 handles things differently looking at the conversion doc, http://durandaljs.com/documentation/Conversion-Guide/. Thank you for your help.